# list recursion in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list. I need to create a a new list, like in example below:
`[3, 3, 1, 3]` to `[3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3]`.
can anybody tell what is wrong with my code?

```
add xs
   = let
      adding (x : xs) as
         =
            if x == head(xs) && length(xs) >= 1
               then adding xs (x : as)
               else adding xs (x : x : as)
      adding _ as
         = as
   in
   adding xs []
```

ghci tells that there is always empty list is `xs`, but i have `xs length` control.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want your code to do?

Comment: adds one element to the list like in the example

Comment: Your example says `[3, 3, 1, 3]` turns into `[3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3]`. That's more than one element added. Did you mean that each element should be duplicated, resulting in a list of twice the original length? Your example doesn't show that either. Did you intend that the result should be `[3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3]`?

Comment: Well then I still don't know what you're trying to do. Please specify what the output should be for each of these lists: `[1,2,3]`, `[2,2,2]`, `[]`, `[1]`.

Comment: @Neil: I'm fairly sure he wants `concatMap (\(x:xs) -> x:x:xs)) . group`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're ultimately trying to do, but I can help you avoid the "empty list" problem.

When the list `(x:xs)` has one item left in it, `xs == []`.  (For example, if `(x:xs)` contains only the item `1`, then `x == 1`, and `xs == []`).  In this case, `head xs` causes an exception because `head` is not defined for empty lists.

Try changing the line

```
if x == head(xs) && length(xs) >= 1
```

to

```
if length(xs) >= 1 && x == head(xs)
```

After this change, when `xs == []`, `length(xs) >= 1` evaluates to `False`.  Since `False && p == False` for all `p`, Haskell skips evaluating the other expression (`x == head(xs)`), and the exception is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Data.List
add xs = concat $ map (\(x:xs) -> x:x:xs) $ group xs
```

Comment: This looks more readable to me: `add xss = concat [x:x:xs | (x:xs) <- group xss]`

Comment: Complete code & no derivation, explanation, or analysis of OP's attempt. -1